# What's the rewrite syntax for an NGINX regex location?

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

Using NGINX as a load balancer running on `10.1.2.15:9002`, I have a need to rewrite `http://10.1.2.15:9002/proxy.stream?opt=1` to `http://10.1.2.15:9002/app/proxy.stream?opt=1`.

Following are bits from my nginx.conf file:

```
http {
  upstream app_cluster {
    server 10.1.2.23:8080;
    server 10.1.2.25:8080;
  }

  server {
    listen 9002 default_server;

    location /app/ {
      proxy_pass http://app_cluster/;
    }

    location ~ ^/proxy.stream(.*)$ {
      rewrite ^(.*)$ /app/$request_uri last;
    }
  }
}
```

By the way, I can replace the `rewrite` line with `return 401` (for example), and I can see the 401 HTTP status returned using Chrome Developer Tools, so I know the regex is matching. I just can't get the URI rewritten properly. In fact, I only see the original request with a 406 status in Developer Tools, so I suspect something is wrong with my `rewrite` syntax.

Does anyone see what is wrong with this configuration?

Comment: Try: `location /proxy.stream { rewrite ^ /app$uri last; }`

Comment: @RichardSmith Post your comment as an answer, please, and I will accept it as the answer. It worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `$request_uri` in the *replacement* string of a `rewrite` statement is problematic, as it has not been normalised and also contains the query string, which by default, `rewrite` will append again.

Also, your *replacement* string contains `//`, as you are appending a URI which already has a leading `/`.

The *regular expression* `location` is not necessary, as a prefix or exact match `location` will suffice and is more efficient for `nginx` to process. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for more.

For example:

```
location /proxy.stream { 
    rewrite ^ /app$uri last;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make use of the matching part from the regex instead of `$request_uri`

`rewrite ^(.*)$ /app/$1 last;`